# System.IO.FileNotException and Could not load OBIDISC4NETnative.dll?

Tags: filenotfoundexception

I am facing one new problem in loading Dll in Windows 8.1 WINBOOK tablet.

Problem description:

I have developed C#.NET app and its worked my Laptop (Windows 8.1) fine.
    But 
    When I copy the same app to my Windows 8.1 WINBOOK tablet, it could not run,

`Exception says, System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly "OB`IDISC4NETnative.Dll" or one of its dependencies,

my laptop system cfg is " 64 -bit OS , x64 based processor"

BUT

my tablet system cfg is " 32 -bit OS , x64 based processor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After  installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)  everything works fine.

Comment: Hi Saddam, I am getting same issue with System.Io file not found Error: " Could not load file or assembly 'SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.Windows.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." Could you please help me

Comment: Did you install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) ?

Comment: Yes,I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for windows, let me know your opinion

Comment: after i installed did one reboot then, everything works fine for me.

Comment: how can I include reference of Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package (x86) in my application

Comment: Updated the answer: you should also install VC 2010 x64 version to be sure. In my case reboot was not required.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I  am using Windows 10 home 64 bit OS and Visual studio 2019-IDE,
After installing  Microsoft Visual C++ latest ,getting the same Error
Could not load file or assembly 'OBIDISC4NETnative.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTTOd.png)